# Does SFSafariViewController leak user data?

Tags: ios, security, oauth

This [blog post](https://library.launchkit.io/how-ios-9-s-safari-view-controller-could-completely-change-your-app-s-onboarding-experience-2bcf2305137f) by Rizwan Sattar outlines how to use SFSafariViewController to log a user into your app. He explains that this is possible because SFSafariViewController shares cookies with Safari.app. To me it seems like a developer could be able to determine which sites a user is logged into thus leaking data. I assume though that you would have to pass the site a private key to so that it knows which app URL scheme to redirect to. Is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SFSafariViewController doesn't leak user data - the app doesn't have any access to the webview, cookies, etc.

As you surmise, the way logins work is that the website that is opened would redirect to the app using its registered URL scheme (containing a login token or something like that).

Comment: Rizwan Sattar here. Andrew M. is correct. SFSafariViewController runs out-of-process, and it is not possible to screen scrape my data for any website. Also, the site needs to have custom code that would actually be generating a login token and redirecting back to the app. In my blog post I demo this working with a registered URL scheme, but ideally you will also use iOS 9's universal app links to ensure no one else can hijack the response.

Answer (score 1):

While Andrew M is correct that the SFSafariViewController does not leak data in the literal sense (you can't access the data, the screen, etc), you are correct that you can potentially infer things about the user's sessions using it. Whether this is a major leak is debatable, but you could use it for things like determining if they have a specific app installed.

For example, say there exists some rather sleazy app with it's own URI Scheme, `sleaze://`. I know that if I open the SFSafariViewController with their website, and the user is already logged in, they'll redirect back to their app. Therefore, if I open their web url, and immediately find my app being backgrounded, I can assume that they are users of that app.

Now, is that subtle, or something the user wouldn't realize is obviously wrong? No, obviously not. Perhaps it isn't the perfect example of a "weaponized" version of this, but I think it's along the same lines of what you were thinking.

Comment: I would if you would need to steal the sleazy's app's private key (not impossible) for this to work the way you lay it out.

Comment: Depends on the implementation of the site. If the site auto-redirects for any logged in user, it'd work without it. If they only do it on login, and with a key, then you're right. Like I said, may not be a perfect example, but certainly possible to abuse.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with "Steve Moser". For example: If I am using couple of applications which gets authenticated against the same server (SSO use case) now using SFSafariViewController, can share cookie and be authenticated.
But a rogue application sitting on the same device, will be also able to access that cookie using SFSafariViewContorller, and can get a valid session.